# How to insert span element in a nodeValue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to insert span element in a nodeValue, but it adds to whole element. I only want the span content. How can I do it?

```
let allElements = document.querySelectorAll('*');

allElements.forEach(function (element) {
    element.childNodes.forEach(function (el) {
        if (!el.nodeValue) return;
        el.nodeValue = el.nodeValue.replace(word, `<span class='rainbow'>${word}</span>`);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't, a node value is always plain text, there is no parsing that goes on to create new elements from the value.  I suggest you find a way to use innerHTML.

Comment: @James innerHTML returns the whole element. I only want to edit the content of it

Comment: What you want to do is not very simple, and your method could end up with multiple spans and/or replace substrings in a word etc. This is a little old, but looking at the code in  [link]https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText may give you some ideas.about how best to achieve word replacement.

Comment: @AHaworth, Thanks. This worked.